# react-hook-form with react-select how to save values as an array of values instead of array of option objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-select

I'm using `chakra-react-select` which is basically just a styled Chakra compatible version of `react-select`.

I'm also using `react-hook-form`, I've hooked up the component to work nicely with react form by writing the following bit of code:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  rules={validation}
  render={({ field }) => {
    const Component = isCreatable ? CreatableSelect : Select;

    return (
      <Component
        isRequired={Boolean(validation?.required)}
        isClearable={isClearable}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        isMulti={isMulti}
        isSearchable={isSearchable}
        options={options}
        {...field}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

This works but my only problem is the value that gets saved to the form is not an array of values (which is what I expect). Instead I get an array of selected options (i.e. the entire option object).

I expect: `['value1', 'value2', ...]`

Instead I get `[{ label: 'Value 1', value: 'value1' }, ...]`

What is the neatest way to change they way the data is saved on my form? I can't do it on the submit because my `yup` validations apply the validation rules before the form submit event finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to overwrite the `onChange` and `value` keys from `field` like this:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  rules={validation}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...field } }) => {
    const Component = isCreatable ? CreatableSelect : Select;

    function handleChange(newValue) {
      onChange(getChangedValue(newValue);
    }

    const internalValue = getInitialValue(value)

    return (
      <Component
        isRequired={Boolean(validation?.required)}
        isClearable={isClearable}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        isMulti={isMulti}
        isSearchable={isSearchable}
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={internalValue}
        {...field}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

That is the simple just of it, the values need to be transformed to the string array during `onChange` but then the `internalValue` needs to be derived from the string array and `options`.

---

The full solution which caters for Multiple Selects and Creatable Selects is as follows:

First add this to the top of the component:

```
const [allOptions, setAllOptions] = useState(options);
// `options` is the options prop that you pass to the SelectComponent
```

Then update your Controller as follows:

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  rules={validation}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value, ...field } }) => {
    const Component = isCreatable ? CreatableSelect : Select;

    function handleChange(newValue: SingleValue | MultiValue) {
      handleNewOption({ isCreatable, isMulti, newValue, setAllOptions });
      onChange(getChangedValue({ isMulti, newValue }));
    }

    const internalValue = getInternalValue({ allOptions, isMulti, value });

    return (
      <Component
        isRequired={Boolean(validation?.required)}
        isClearable={isClearable}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        isMulti={isMulti}
        isSearchable={isSearchable}
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={internalValue}
        {...field}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

And then here are the helper functions:

```
interface GetChangeValueArgs {
  isMulti: boolean;
  newValue: SingleValue | MultiValue;
}

export function getChangedValue(
{ isMulti, newValue }: GetChangeValueArgs
): MultiValue | SingleValue {
  if (!newValue) {
    return null;
  }
  if (isMulti) {
    return (newValue as MultiValue).map(
      (v) => v.value
    ) as MultiValue;
  }
  return newValue.value as SingleValue;
}

interface GetInternalValueArgs<T> {
  allOptions: FormSelectOption<T>[];
  isMulti: boolean;
  value: T | T[];
}
export function getInternalValue(
  { allOptions, isMulti, value }: GetInternalValueArgs<T>
) {
  if (isMulti) {
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    return (value as T[])
      .map((optionValue) =>
        allOptions.find((option) => option.value === optionValue)
      )
      .reduce((valueItems, valueItem) => {
        if (!valueItem) {
          return valueItems;
        }

        return [...valueItems, valueItem];
      }, []);
  }
  return allOptions.find((option) => option.value === value) || null;
}

interface HandleNewOptionArgs<T> {
  isCreatable: boolean;
  isMulti: boolean;
  newValue: SingleValue<FormSelectOption<T>> | MultiValue<FormSelectOption<T>>;
  setAllOptions: Dispatch<SetStateAction<FormSelectOption<T>[]>>;
}

export function handleNewOption({
  isMulti,
  isCreatable,
  newValue,
  setAllOptions,
}: HandleNewOptionArgs) {
  if (isCreatable && newValue) {
    if (isMulti) {
      newValue.forEach((newOption) => {
        if ('__isNew__' in newOption && newOption.__isNew__) {
          setAllOptions((prevOptions) => [...prevOptions, newOption]);
        }
      });
    } else {
      if (
        newValue &&
        '__isNew__' in newValue &&
        newValue.__isNew__
      ) {
        setAllOptions((prevOptions) => [...prevOptions, newValue]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```